# sort a list in numerical order that has letter(s)

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
list = ["a9", "a11", "a6", "a2", "a4", "a12", "a10", "a15", "a17"]
```

From this list I would want to sort the list so that the numbers behind 'a' is in numerical order. Is there a simple way to do this?

output wanted:

```
list = ["a2", "a4", "a6", "a9", "a10", "a11", "a12", "a15", "a17"]
```

Comment: Use `key=lambda x: int(x.lstrip('a'))`?

Comment: list.sort(key=lambda x: int(x[1:])) for any first character

Comment: Interesting to generalize this *puzzle* - if List has *b01, b11, b02* ...?